# SWF file loaded with loadMovie doesn't work with getBytesLoaded or stop, play, etc

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I load a swf into a movie clip and have several problems with it:

```
blah_mc.loadMovie("my.swf");

blah_mc.stop(); // doesn't work
trace(blah_mc.getBytesLoaded()); // always returns zero even though the clip plays
```

These problems persist *even after the clip is completely loaded*.

I need to be able to control playback of the loaded movie and tell what percent it is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getBytesLoaded()` never really worked for me in AS2 either (the AS3 version was better-behaved).  The solution is called `MovieClipLoader`; check the language reference.

Comment: Unfortunately I only have Flash 8.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the stop() etc right after the loadMovie like that? It's probably way too soon to get a sensible result if you are.
Set up an interval to give it a little space, or look at using one of those MovieClipLoader classes.
If you are not doing that, then I don't think I have enough context to help.